# Meteor Google APIs OAuth2 Implementation

Tags: node.js, meteor, reactjs, oauth, google-api

I'm working on a [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) app and looking to implement OAuth2 so users can link their Google Analytics account and view stats within this Meteor App.

I've included the [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) NPM package within my Meteor project via:

`meteor npm install googleapis --save`

When I go to import the package, it causes the Meteor app to fail to load. I'm importing the package like:

`import google from 'googleapis';`

and using it like:

`const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;`

This is the console error I get back when I try to load the app:

`Uncaught TypeError: fs.readdirSync is not a function | encrypter.js:62`

I've also tried this import method:

`import { Oauth2 } from 'googleapis';`

Comment: Try `const google = require('googleapis');`. https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#using-npm

Answer (score 0):

From the error you get it seems that you are trying to include the `googleapis` package in client code. The package only works on the server, so make sure you only include it in code that is either included from the `server/` folder or within a `if (Meteor.isServer)` block.